# Any way to cause SQL Server to parse query in multiple lines so error reporting is more accurate?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I might be overlooking more robust error reporting, but currently error reporting for SQL Server just gives me a line number (which is effectively only 1 line) for non-syntactical errors.

Today a client had ',' in the price value, but dealing with 72 or so fields this took me quite awhile to find just given a cannot cast to float message.

I was thinking maybe I could force sql to run the code in multiple lines so that the line number would be a much more useful bit of info.

I tried line break, putting in new lines, and adding new line characters but non of those worked.

Does anybody know a way to do this, or have a good method for tracking down these errors?

Comment: No this isn't possible. Nor does it really make sense for the vast majority of runtime errors to try and associate them back to a specific line in the source code.

Comment: ...was just hoping. That makes me wonder why it doesnt work this way.

Comment: After the query is compiled it is stored as an execution plan that doesn't really have any obvious mapping back to the source text. Conceptually the statement executes "all at once" as well. Some connect items to improve error reporting are http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/774754/new-virtual-table-errors-it-would-analogous-to-the-deleted-and-inserted-tables and https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/339410/please-fix-the-string-or-binary-data-would-be-truncated-message-to-give-the-column-name though.

Comment: Interesting. This really answers my question. thankyou good sir.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try the TRY_CONVERT in the fields are not set as varchar; I mean you can apply this function to dates, numbers, and other not character data.

You can take a look at the example:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230993.aspx

Hope it helps!

Comment: That would certainly be better to add to most fields than the mess I have at the moment. Good suggestion.